# Django - How to restrict which user can connect to the socket?

Tags: python, django, sockets, websocket, channel

I am using django channels for an application [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io), and i want to restrict access to the socket (authorized users only).

Have this:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def connect_blog(message, username):
    user = message.user

    try:
        user_blog = User.objects.get(username=username)
        has_perm = user_blog.check_perm(user.pk)
        if not has_perm:
            return
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        message.reply_channel.send({
            # WebSockets send either a text or binary payload each frame.
            # We do JSON over the text portion.
            "text": json.dumps({"error": "bad_slug"}),
            "close": True,
        })
        return
    Group(user_blog.group_name).add(message.reply_channel)
```

But **when I check the permissions has already been connected to the socket**, how can I control this? (How to close the socket or control this case).

Thanks and regards.

Comment: So, did you find any solution?

Comment: @AnnShress No, not yet.

Comment: @AnnShress in django-channels >= 2.0 you can use AuthMiddlewareStack

Comment: It's been a long time since I last checked channels. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [good tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html) about Django channels.

And my solution for authentication:

```
async def connect(self):
    self.user = self.scope["user"]
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['id']
    self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

    if self.user.is_authenticated: # also you can add more restrictions here
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
```

Don't foget about `routing.py` in the root:

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import rooms.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            rooms.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

You can view the full code of my `consumers.py` [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/sZuU3KXq).